# Playwright selector for dynamic attribute

Tags: typescript, dynamic, attributes, playwright

I have a button component, when clicked, displays a pop-up. To establish relationship between the button and the pop-up, an attribute is added to the button dynamically called "aria-controls". The value in "arial-controls" is the "id" of the pop-up.
Does Playwright locator support attributes that were added dynamically? I would like to get the value of "aria-controls" so I can locate the pop-up correctly.

Comment: I would use either ```.or()```->[ref](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-or) or append to your button the "arial-controls" by using ```.and()```->[ref](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-and) after you clicked the button

Comment: Please share the page--there's often a better approach to selecting it than an ['or'](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-or), although that is supported by PW.